# Chrome Console error for Youtube API Ouath verifcation,Refused to display: in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-client, x-frame-options

Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=******' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

[click here to see the chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Hga.jpg)

while Executing googleApiClientReady() code in auth.js

```
  // Upon loading, the Google APIs JS client automatically invokes this callback.
    googleApiClientReady = function() {
      gapi.auth.init(function() {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like

gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: clientId,
      
      scope: scopes,
      immediate: immediate
    }, handleAuthResult);

Comment: in Question : window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);

doing already like that in chechAuth method as same as what you mentioned.